# ScriptResource.axd attack is it possible?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, xss

This is code from site source genereted by firefox

```
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=K-bZ_cYro-TWH0gbbmdTlkin59eWVsDQYopNlGtfNYd9aZQqi22u0d_A5dwpqMXbaJR99E08UDAgSF7tPCaP0mpZH35-uv4YYRWnSX0mxLsZPGu-58i2Nrmb8UHNokeftpIW9wTPOvZOJJq4cLYfu3iV8EQ1&amp;t=634475972033675436" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and in internetExploerer it is different:

```
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=D9IFE4zJbSW6xdBnMDVoHa7cjuZLxGMz5rJdExBH42SKXYYNLX-7YyB353XNYzdNn_wv9n8ymQQJPRpsWSgxaxRNJXjxBfAjOtowaCqEOoqkTfCwaB1sP8qQsIM2egutH-T079r_BOxt__VlBgi-GyM8WHA1&amp;t=6df0ad7a" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Site behaves strange right now.

Is it possible thjat someone is making any attacks ?

Comment: What do the scripts look like.

Answer (score 1):

The blob in the `d` parameter is encrypted for security reasons.  It will be different on each request.